# What does "life-sentenced quality" mean?

Tags: meaning

> [All I hear is how they argue -- the spite and anger in the man's voice, the **life-sentenced quality** of the woman's voice.](https://www.randomhouse.com/boldtype/1100/mitchell/essay.html)

Comment: That would be the "quality common to people who have been sentenced to life in prison"; someone who is trapped, and bitter, who has no way to escape or to win; and who knows it, and has a bleak, suffering mentality because of it.

Comment: @Hellion sounds good. Would you mind to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be the "quality common to people who have been sentenced to life in prison"; someone who is trapped, and bitter, who has no way to escape or to win; and who knows it, and has a bleak, suffering mentality because of it.